# Помогите решить задачу python

Tags: python

Пользователь вводит три числа. Найти количество чисел, которые делятся на 3. Если таких чисел нет, то вывести сумму этих чисел.

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
s = 0
if a % 3 == 0:
    s = s+1
elif b % 3 == 0:
    s = s+1
elif c % 3 == 0:
    s =s+1
else:
    s=(a+b+c)
print(s)
```

Comment: Замените `elif` на `if`, иначе у вас только одно число будет подсчитано. `else` замените на `if s == 0`. `s = s+1` я бы заменил на `s += 1` :)

Answer (score 2):

Я сделал только маленькие поправки, чтобы ваш код правильно работал:

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
s = 0
if a % 3 == 0:
    s = s+1
if b % 3 == 0:
    s = s+1
if c % 3 == 0:
    s =s+1
if s == 0:      # значит, нет числа, которое делиться на 3
    s=(a+b+c)
print(s)
```

Именно

- никаких `else`, потому что вы во всяком случае хотите *проверять все 3 числа,*
- когда код уже установил количество чисел, делящихся на 3, возможно тестировать *сравнением с нулем*, если такие числа существуют, и когда нет, заменить их (нулевое) количество суммой.